# cant connect my managedObjectContext from my view to my Delegate

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

i'm using core data on my app and i know i need to connect my `managedObjectContext` throw the Delegate but i don't know how...
i have a delegate-
**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *nav;


- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

---

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "mainViewController.h"
#import "addViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize nav;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //----------------------------------nav-------------------------------------------------
    mainViewController*mainView=[[mainViewController alloc]init];
    nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainView];
    mainView.manageObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];
    //----------------------------------nav-end---------------------------------------------
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

the MainVeiw is not the page that i want to save an Entity in (so i cant Match the objects from the delegate itself), that is another page and i think my problem is that i dont know how to import a delegate id object so i can compare the `managedObjectContext` to the one on my delegate.

**addViewController.h:**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface addViewController : UIViewController  <UIPickerViewAccessibilityDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *allSubjects;
    NSArray* arrSubject;
    NSArray* arrSubSubjects;
    NSManagedObjectContext*manageObjectContext;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSManagedObjectContext*manageObjectContext;
//@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
//@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *allSubjects;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* arrSubject;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* arrSubSubjects;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrolladdview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerSubjects;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtDesc;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

-(IBAction)createPassword:(id)sender;


@end
```

**addViewController.m**

```
#import "addViewController.h"


@interface addViewController ()

@end

@implementation addViewController
@synthesize allSubjects,arrSubject,arrSubSubjects,pickerSubjects;
@synthesize txtDesc,txtPassword,txtUserName,scrolladdview,manageObjectContext;



-(IBAction)createPassword:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row;
    NSString*subTypeSelectd=[[NSString alloc]init];

    row = [pickerSubjects selectedRowInComponent:0];
    subTypeSelectd = [arrSubSubjects objectAtIndex:row];

    NSInteger row2;
    NSString*TypeSelectd=[[NSString alloc]init];

    row2 = [pickerSubjects selectedRowInComponent:1];
    TypeSelectd = [arrSubSubjects objectAtIndex:row2];


//here is the error: no visible @interface for 'addViewController' declares the selector 'NSManagedObject' 
    NSManagedObject*password=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Password" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];


    [password setValue:self.txtDesc.text forKey:@"desc"];
    [password setValue:self.txtUserName.text forKey:@"userName"];
    [password setValue:self.txtPassword.text forKey:@"password"];
    [password setValue:subTypeSelectd forKey:@"subType"];
    [password setValue:TypeSelectd forKey:@"type"];

    NSError*error;
    if(![[self manageObjectContext]save:&error])
        NSLog(@"input %@",error);
    else NSLog(@"saved");

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

i will love some help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could get it form the AppDelegate itself:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

//...

-(IBAction)createPassword:(id)sender
{
//...
NSManagedObjectContext* context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]). managedObjectContext;
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in I see, you have created one context in the AppDelegate, and one in the Addviewcontroller.
Where as you have only one store and one thread, so you should remove the property of the managed object context from the AddviewController.
Also should assign the managedobjectcontext from the delegate in the addViewController by the following code:

{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *addViewcontrollerLocalContext  = delegate.managedObjectContext;
}

By doing this all the objects would be saved in the MainObjectContext created by you in the AppDelegate file.